# is there a way to check a divs id and class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to refine the question and be more specific lets say I wanted to search through divs with a certain class name. ex.

```
<div id ="1" class="head"></div>
<div id ="2" class="head"></div>
<div id ="3" class="head"></div>

if(div.id != "1")
{
   add class to all divs not = 1
}
```

how would this work
thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you wan't to check if a div has a specific `id` and a specific class?

Comment: yes I want to check the entire page for a specific div

Answer (score 3):

- If `div` is an `Element` object:

  ```
  if (div.id == 'blah' && div.className == 'blablah') {
  ```
- If `div` is a given jQuery object, use the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method, combined with the id (`#`) and class (`.`) selector:

  ```
  if (div.is('#blah.blahblah')) {
  ```
- If you want to check if there's any `<div>` which matches these rules:

  ```
  if ($('div#blah.blahblah').length) {
  ```

Comment: `div.className` could contain multiple classes.

Comment: @Rocket  The question said `div class =blahblah`, not `div class like blabla`. If the OP wants to check whether it *has* the class, he can use `div.className.indexOf('blablah') !== -1` instead.

Comment: I know, just figured I'd point that out just in case the OP didn't realize it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the div's ID using `$(div).attr('id')` or `div.id`.  As for class, you can check `.hasClass`.

```
if($(div).attr('id') === 'blah' && $(div).hasClass('blahblah'))
```

Answer (score 0):

given the markup:

```
<div class='myhappyclass other' id='yodudeid'>hi</div>

$('div').each(function() {
    var myi = $(this).attr('id');
    var myc = $(this).attr('class');
    alert("id:" + myi + " class:" + myc);
    if (myi == 'yodudeid' && $(this).hasClass('other')) {
        alert('yepper');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following show work, but not tested.

```
if(($('#blah').length) && ($('.blahblah').length)){
    then do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your little example above, to achieve this, just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[id!=1]").addClass('{your class name}');
});
```

If you actually wanted to check for a specific element with id and class you could take advantage of the jquery each function which loops through elements matching your criteria as follows:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == '2' && $(this).attr('class') == 'head')
    {
    $(this).addClass('{your class name}');
    }
});
```